# How to debug a Word OfficeJs command-only add-in

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, office-js

I am trying to write my first JavaScript Word add-in using Visual Studio Code. As a basis I used the [Simple Word Add-in example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/Simple) provided by Microsoft. The example puts all JavaScript code in the commands.html file. I would like to put my code in the separate commands.js file, and use the [Word Javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=word-js-preview) instead of the [Common API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office). But with most changes Word just does not respond and I can't see what's happening at this stage.

I have installed the [Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension). All examples that I have seen are task pane add-ins, and I was able to attach a debugger to those examples. Is there any way to debug a command add-in (without a task pane)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger Extension for Visual Studio Code will not work for debugging commands. In order to debug commands, your best bet is to upload your add-in manifest to Office Online, view it in Edge or Chrome and use the DevTools (F12).  You should be able to add the add-in project source in the DevTools and just set breakpoints in the commands.

If you are running the Edge Chromium (which I don't think you are based on the fact that Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger Extension worked for taskpane add-ins), debugging commands can all be done in VS Code.

Comment: FYI, the tagline of your name isn't needed, as it's already provided by the user profile info in the lower right of the Answer. Otherwise this looks like a good Answer.